# Difference between gem versions on rubygems.org and github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, github

In my rails app when I do the following in my `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` I end up with one version of the gem, say 1.2

```
gem 'some_gem'  # gets me version 1.2
```

But then on github.com the version might be past 1.2, say up to 1.4. Sometimes the newer version (1.4) will contain some fix I need for my project. So I'll change my gemfile like so

```
gem 'some_gem', :git => 'git://github.com/someone/some_gem.git'  # v 1.4
```

I have 2 questions related to this.

1 - why are the versions different? Is it simply because the version on rubygems.org needs to be stable? Currently I'm running `gem query --remote --name-matches some_gem` but I'm looking for something easier/automated.

2 - is there an easy way to know when the rubygems.org version of a gem gets updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author has to choose to publish to Rubygems from their Github repository and sometimes they hold off thinking that the Github version needs more work.

Doing `gem update` will bring down any updated versions of Gems without you looking for them. other than that I think it is just looking for the Gem on Rubygems and seeing if their is an update.